# Sum of ByteArray Always Equals Sum Of String in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, string, kotlin

```
val a = "string1"
val b = "string2"
val result = (a + b).toByteArray().contentEquals(a.toByteArray() + b.toByteArray())
```

Is the above result always true no matter what the string is?

Comment: I wonder why you want to know that...

Comment: I would assume yes... the concatenated string might not always look the same as the single ones, but otherwise for the comparison it should be equal... you could probably test it with complete random strings (e.g. `String(Random.nextBytes(..))`) ...

Answer (score 0):

Since in both scenarios we're concatenating the same two `String`s, but with different formats, the answer is [yes](https://pl.kotl.in/t0rKfM_L_?theme=darcula) and the reason for that is the actual content is always equal to the content of `a + b`.

Answer (score 0):

`Strings` are a sequence of `characters`, and data types are stored as bytes.

Byte array representations of `a` and `b` are

`string1 = [115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 49]`

`string2 = [115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 50]`

So, concatenating `string1` and `string2` is same as concatenating their byte arrays.

If you exchange `a` and `b`, the sum won't be the same.

As `(a + b).toByteArray()` is `[115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 49, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 50]`

and `b.toByteArray() + a.toByteArray()` is `[115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 50, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 49]`